# unable to open my .aspx page in IIS,windows server2003 R2 Enterprise version

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, iis, windows-server-2003

Dear All,
please help iam hanged..i  deployed my Asp.Net website in iis.but i unable to open my aspx page while i browse..but can open Html pages..i did everything..
same thing i done in vista and Xp its working fine..but while i trying to do in Windows Server2003 R2 enterprise server its not working

please help what could be the problem...

Comment: If you "did everything", I don't know how you expect us to help. But since you could not possibly have done "everything", it would help to know exactly what you DID do... and exactly what your error is. "Cannot open" means absolutely nothing.

Comment: i mean to say is..which is done in PC same i have done is Server..i cpoied published file in Wwwroot and in IIS i created virtual dir and mapped to published folder in wwwrrot->xxx.i set properties like port no and Asp.net version in IIS.and i tried to browse .its not open my login.aspx..what shall i do.? And Error is page can't be displayed..HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found.
Internet Information Services (IIS)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some some things to check.  I apologize in advance, but I don't have a server in front of me to verify some of the specifics of where things are --

1) Make sure the site is configured to use the correct version of ASP.NET.  You can see the version in the Site's Properies tab.

2)  If the version of .NET you need is not showing up and is installed on the server, run "regiis.exe -i" from your framework directory to register the framework with IIS.

3) If you're running this on a 64-bit server, check the Web Extensions section in IIS to make sure you "allow" whatever looks right.